# Australia visa application for work and holiday

Tags: legal, australia, working-holiday, criminal-records

Last summer, in 2016, I traveled to Australia with a tourist visa, staying for 3 months. I'm from Chile.

- I got a speeding ticket and fine in Melbourne in February. I didn't pay the fine in the given period, so my case went to court. After that, I came back to Chile and did the payment from here, with all the extra taxes because of the 4 month's delay. Case closed.
- I went to a private hospital in Melbourne in February. I had insurance, so I paid everything right then (AUD $400). But, after a few weeks, I received a letter from the hospital that I owe for additional things that no one told me about at the time. I tried to call and email the hospital to check that issue, but no reply.
- I left  the student residence with an unpaid debt (AUD150). Again, I have been trying for months to get in touch with them and no reply.

Questions:
 - Is a speeding fine a criminal records offense, and will I have problems in applying for a work and holiday visa? 
 - If they give me visa, will I have problems entering Australia?

In any case, I have been trying to reach them, but no reply and I want to pay everything, whether they give me the visa or not.